# How to call WCF REST/JSON Service from client application

Tags: c#, wcf, json, rest

I have WCF REST/JSON Service, I create it by using [this](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fbc7e5c1-a0d2-41bd-9d7b-e54c845394cd) template. In my service I have a method

```
 [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "Create", Method = "*",RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    public void Create(PictureData pictureData)
    {
        var context = new EFDBContext();
        context.PictureData.Add(pictureData);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

PictureData this my entity data, which I try to save in DB via EF.

In my WPF client application I try to call this method:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient("http://localhost:8080/ScreenPictureService/Create"))
        {
            var dataContract = HttpContentExtensions.CreateJsonDataContract(pictureData);
            client.Post("", dataContract);
        }
```

**But nothing happen**

- I also try to use Method="POST" in WebInvoke attribute
- Also I try to use address without "Create" in HttpClient and then use it in client.Post in first parameter

**UPDATE**

After I try this

```
var dataContract = HttpContentExtensions.CreateJsonDataContract(pictureData, typeof (PictureData));
        var client = new HttpClient();
        using(var response = client.Post("http://localhost:8080/ScreenPictureService/Create", dataContract))
        {
            response.EnsureStatusIs(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

I have received Bad Request 400

**UPDATE 2**
I found my problems:

- I use [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/) to serialize my object, and when I receive byte array it convert to base64 format, but my service expect byte array - it solved to use list of bytes.
- And second problem - I try to receive screnshot of my desctop with high defenition, and i have the same response(Bad Request 400), if I change picture resolution to 800x600, service works well, and there is my question - How to increase quota of request message. I try yo use, inside standardEndpoint section(web.config)

*readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxDepth="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"*

But it doesn't work

Comment: What do you mean by nothing happens ? Are there any errors ? Did you check the events log ?

Comment: I mean, that no errors was received.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried monitoring the exact request / response with a tool like Fiddler? Perhaps your post is not as you would expect it to be?

Does the WCF service know to accept REST? If you are not using the [WCF.WebApi](http://wcf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WCF%20HTTP) there is usually the horrible wcf bindings to configure, eg:

```
<service name="MyWcfServiceWebRole.xyz.IAbcService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="webby" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="RestBinding" contract="MyWcfServiceWebRole.xyz.IAbcService" />
</service>

<behaviors>
   <endpointBehaviors>
      <behavior name="webby">
         <webHttp />
      </behavior>
   </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Does a simple REST Get work?

Comment: I try to monitoring with Fiddler, it also receive Bad Request 400. Yes a simple REST works well.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [Hammock](https://github.com/danielcrenna/hammock), it's easy and works well.

Answer (score 0):

The error 400 Bad request can be due to many possiblities. Try enabling tracing on your service. It can be done by following the link [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx).

Also if you have a config file with configuration make sure you have the readerQuotas sepecified as below if you are using webHttpBinding:

```
<webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="RestBinding">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="16384"
        maxBytesPerRead="4096" />
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
```

If you are using the REST API with defining your service with routes in global.asax and using a standard endpoint use the below:

```
<standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true">
    <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="5242880" maxArrayLength="4194304"
            maxBytesPerRead="4194304" />
</standardEndpoint>
```